# MS Access VBA Delete Empty Folders

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a list of folder paths I need to delete on a regular basis via an Access program.  I only want to delete them if all of the sub folders are empty.  How do I delete an empty folder via VBA?  This is my code but it doesn't do anything.

I call it via:

```
PrepareDirModified ("C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Desktop\New folder\TEST123\test456")
```

Here is the main sub:

```
Public Sub PrepareDirModified(dirStr As String)
On Error Resume Next
    If Right(dirStr, 1) <> "\" Then dirStr = dirStr & "\"
    Kill dirStr & "*.*"
    RmDir dirStr
    MkDir dirStr
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the FileScripting Object to delete a whole series of files then folders, something like;

```
   Dim FSO As Object   

   Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
   On Error GoTo FileError
            'Delete files
   FSO.deletefile mypath & "\*.*", True
            'Delete subfolders
   FSO.deletefolder mypath & "\*.*", True
```

The below blatantly copied from Ron's excellent site https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win003.htm

You can check a folder exists using the same object;

```
Dim FSO As Object
Dim FolderPath As String

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

FolderPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"
If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    FolderPath = FolderPath & "\"
End If

If FSO.FolderExists(FolderPath) = False Then
    MsgBox "Folder doesn't exist"
Else
    MsgBox "Folder exist"
End If
```

And you can check if a file exists in the same way;

```
  Dim FSO As Object
Dim FilePath As String

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

FilePath = "C:\Users\Ron\test\book1.xlsm"

If FSO.FileExists(FilePath) = False Then
    MsgBox "file doesn't exist"
Else
    MsgBox "File exist"
End If
End Sub
```

In order to iterate through the folders I would use this script;

```
    Public Sub DeleteEmptyFolders(ByVal strFolderPath As String)
   Dim fsoSubFolders As Folders
   Dim fsoFolder As Folder
   Dim fsoSubFolder As Folder

   Dim strPaths()
   Dim lngFolder As Long
   Dim lngSubFolder As Long

   DoEvents

   Set m_fsoObject = New FileSystemObject
   If Not m_fsoObject.FolderExists(strFolderPath) Then Exit Sub

   Set fsoFolder = m_fsoObject.GetFolder(strFolderPath)

   On Error Resume Next

   'Has sub-folders
   If fsoFolder.SubFolders.Count > 0 Then
        lngFolder = 1
        ReDim strPaths(1 To fsoFolder.SubFolders.Count)
        'Get each sub-folders path and add to an array
        For Each fsoSubFolder In fsoFolder.SubFolders
            strPaths(lngFolder) = fsoSubFolder.Path
            lngFolder = lngFolder + 1
        Next fsoSubFolder

        lngSubFolder = 1
        'Recursively call the function for each sub-folder
        Do While lngSubFolder < lngFolder
           Call DeleteEmptyFolders(strPaths(lngSubFolder))
           lngSubFolder = lngSubFolder + 1
        Loop
    End If

    'No sub-folders or files
    If fsoFolder.Files.Count = 0 And fsoFolder.SubFolders.Count = 0 Then
        fsoFolder.Delete
    End If
    End Sub
```

Copied from here http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=7821

Comment: thanks for this - how would I modify so it would only delete empty subfolders?

Comment: Please see the edits -  Check for *.* in the file exists option, if it doesn't then you can safely delete the folder.

Comment: thanks for this.  This is looking for a specific filename though.  I want to pass a root folder and then delete all empty subfolders in the root.

Comment: See the added iteration through folders function.